# How to simulate onChange event on input type text in react using jest or enzyme for functional components using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

This is my component file Upload.jsx

```
function Upload() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ tool: 'load-runner' });
    return(
        <Form.Group>                                            
            <Form.Label className="text-light">Student ID</Form.Label>                                                
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="B-XXXXX" onChange={event => setFormData({ ...formData, StudentID: event.target.value })} />                                            
        </Form.Group>
    )
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using for Fom.Label and Form.Control?

Comment: We are using 'react-bootstrap' and using jest and enzyme for test cases, Also we are using react hooks, functional components